# Nginx auth off whole folder

Tags: magento, nginx

We're trying to setup Klaviyo on our Zandbox/test site with nginx.

But Klaviyo cant get the data from SOAP when i have htpasswd enabled.
It needs to visit www.mytestdomain.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1 to get the data.

How can i disable auth_basic for the whole api folder? i already did this for some php files, but as this is not a specific php file i dont know. The code i use for php files is:

```
location =  /folder/file.php {
  auth_basic off;
  try_files $uri =404;
  expires off;
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  proxy_connect_timeout  2600s;
  proxy_send_timeout  2600s;
  proxy_read_timeout  2600s;
  fastcgi_send_timeout 2600s;
  fastcgi_read_timeout 2600s;
  fastcgi_pass zandbox;
  fastcgi_pass_request_headers on;
  fastcgi_keep_conn off;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root${fastcgi_script_name};
  fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE base;
  fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE website;
  }
```

The Full code:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.dk www.mydomain.dk;
    return 301 https://www.mydomain.dk$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name mydomain.dk;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/www_mydomain_dk.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/www_mydomain_dk.key;
  include /etc/nginx/ssl_common.conf;

  return 301 https://www.mydomain.dk$request_uri;

}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name www.mydomain.dk;

  auth_basic "Restricted";
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

  location = /api/ {
     auth_basic "off";
  }

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/www_mydomain_dk.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/www_mydomain_dk.key;
  include /etc/nginx/ssl_common.conf;

  root /var/www/www.mydomain.dk/deployed/current;
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://www.mydomain.dk";
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://mydomain.dk";

  include /etc/nginx/common.d/top_common.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/common.d/locations.conf;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    expires off;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    proxy_connect_timeout  2600s;
    proxy_send_timeout  2600s;
    proxy_read_timeout  2600s;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 2600s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 2600s;
    fastcgi_pass mydomain;
    fastcgi_pass_request_headers on;
    fastcgi_keep_conn off;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root${fastcgi_script_name};
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE base;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE website;
  }

  location =  /bridge_xcxcdd.php {
    auth_basic off;
    try_files $uri =404;
    expires off;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    proxy_connect_timeout  2600s;
    proxy_send_timeout  2600s;
    proxy_read_timeout  2600s;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 2600s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 2600s;
    fastcgi_pass mydomain;
    fastcgi_pass_request_headers on;
    fastcgi_keep_conn off;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root${fastcgi_script_name};
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE base;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE website;
  }

location =  /api {
        auth_basic off;
        try_files $uri =404;
        expires off;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        proxy_connect_timeout  2600s;
        proxy_send_timeout  2600s;
        proxy_read_timeout  2600s;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 2600s;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 2600s;
        fastcgi_pass mydomain;
        fastcgi_pass_request_headers on;
        fastcgi_keep_conn off;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root${fastcgi_script_name};
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE base;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE website;
      }

}
```

Comment: Post complete config that you have tried. This won't do.

Comment: Sure. I have added the full code now :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I tried lots of configs and finally one worked out. The main learning was not to put basic auth in server block, rather use location blocks. And then instead of calling php outside, use nested blocks, so restrictions can be inherited.

Below I will showcase a echo only structure which does the Job, you just need to modify your config in this style

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        satisfy any;

        location / {
            auth_basic "Restricted";
            auth_basic_user_file /var/www/html/.htpasswd;
            echo "Restricted URL";

            location /api/ {
                auth_basic "off";

                echo "you reach /api";

                location ~ \.php$ {
                    echo "You reached unauthenticated php";
                }
            }

            location ~ \.php$ {
                echo "You reached authenticated php";
            }
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            echo "You reached php";
        }
    }
}
```

Below are my test

```
$ curl -u tarun:tarun localhost/abc/test.php
You reached authenticated php

$ curl -u tarun:tarun localhost/test.php
You reached authenticated php

$ curl localhost/test.php
<html>
<head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>401 Authorization Required</h1></center>
<hr><center>openresty/1.11.2.2</center>
</body>
</html>

$ curl localhost/api/test.php
You reached unauthenticated php

$ curl localhost/api/test
you reach /api
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you so much! cant say thank you enough!